# Indexer in Generic Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, indexer

Hi 
i have created a Generic Array that works fine for Int,String, Float or even my Own type named Customers.

Generic Array has functions Add(), Sort(), ShowAll() thats working fine for Int, String, and even Customer Type 
except when i try to showAll() method for CustomerType that shows all the values that i have added through ADD() method.

output is something like 
`GenericArray.Customer`

not the values where as i wanted to have the values .

i have solved it through

**`public class GArray<T> where T : Customer`**

but now i cant create Generic Array of type Int,Float .

here is the ADD and ShowAll method of Class

```
public void Add(T temp)
        {

            if (index >= values.Length)
            {
                T[] tempArray = new T[values.Length + 1];
                Array.Copy(values, tempArray, values.Length);
                values = tempArray;
            }
            values[index] = temp;
            index++;  
        }

 public void ShowAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values[i]);                
        }
    }
```

the values m adding

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {                        
            GArray<Customer> customers = new GArray<Customer>(3);
            customers.Add(new Customer(101, "xyz"));
            customers.Add(new Customer(59, "abc"));

            customers.ShowAll();
            }
```

i have talked with my frnd and he said that i have to create indexer my self . can some one help me how can i create indexer in this case that works fine for customerType or any Type.

Comment: lmgtfy? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: By Indexer, do you mean enumerator or some `GetValueByIndex(int)` function?

Comment: Why didn't you extend `List<T>`? It already does dynamic allocation under the hood (and a bit more efficiently, since you are reallocating in 1 byte increments every time).

Comment: Groo i wish i cld have extended List but there was restriction from my teacher so i have to extend simple Array :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,If I understand the question (*output is something like GenericArray.Customer, not the values where as i wanted to have the values*) you should add in Customer definition:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // return something you want to show to identify your customer
    // e.g. return Name;  
    return ...           
}
```

I explain: when you use `Console.WriteLine(values[i])` you tell C# to write to console Customer object... and it writes out then name of the class, as it's the default behaviour.
Defining in Customer class the default string to be converted to makes what you please...

Comment: You don't need to add the ToString call to the Console.WriteLine call -- Console.WriteLine is already calling ToString. The default implementation, in System.Object, simply displays the class name. All the OP needs to do is add the override.

Comment: U understood question Rite and ur Solution solved my Problem thankz for Your Help .. Thank You very Much :) u saved my Life :d

Comment: @user751959: if I could really save some life just by typing on my keyboard, it will be really great!!! ;) Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public T this[int index]
{
  get {return values[index]; }
}
```

Comment: i have tried ur solution but it didnt helped me can u plz elaborate more. it wld be good if i be able to solve it through indexers

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not overridden ToString in your customer class.  Do that -- it will define how the objects should be displayed in the console.

Comment: I think the same and I've already posted some code... this makes me think I've understood the question :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm typing on my phone so it took me a long time to get that short answer out. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem aside for a moment, I would like to mention that there is no place for a `ShowAll` method in an array implementation. Why should an array be tied to a console application? Wouldn't you want to reuse it for a Windows Forms application oneday without the need to rewrite it?

Next, .NET already has a `List<T>` which does dynamic allocation as necessary. If you do want to write it again yourself, at least allocate the array in bigger steps (n*2 each time).

To remove the `ShowAll` method from the array (where it doesn't belong), you should consider taking one of the following approaches:

a) Create an extension method which works for any `IEnumerable<T>` (a List, Array, Collection, whatever):

```
 public static class EnumExt
{
     public static void ShowAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
     {
         foreach (T item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1,2,3};
array.ShowAll();
```

b) Or, be even more abstract and create a `ForEach` extension method where you will pass an arbitrary `delegate` to perform actual work:

```
public static class EnumExt
{
     public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
     {
         foreach (T item in list)
            action(item);
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1,2,3};
// now you are reusing the iterator
// for any action you want to execute
array.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
// or
array.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine("My item is: " + item));
```